# Ruby Threads Die?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've been playing around with threads but I keep running into a problem where the treads seem to just die or stop.

Whats going on here? And how do I get round it?

I've included the code, but didn't paste it here as I think this problem is more fundamental to ruby.
[source code](http://pastie.org/1806689)

thanks.

**Edit**
Ruby 1.8, MacOS (snow leopard)

Comment: "I've included the code, but didn't paste it here as I think this problem is more fundamental to ruby." - repeat after me: select isn't broken!

Comment: @Andrew Grimm. Select isn't broken @Frank Schmitt MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got threads randomly "going away", make sure you've set `Thread.abort_on_exception` to `true`. That'll stop the interpreter if an uncaught exception reaches the top-level in a background thread (via `SystemExit`, so don't `rescue Exception` or they'll get swallowed), and can be immensely useful in tracking down random bugs.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're forgetting to add your new Thread objects to your threads object.

```
3.times do |t|
  threads << Thread.new { word_list.process }
end
```

Your threads.each {|t| t.join} is working on an empty array, and so is ignoring the threads you did create.  Make the change and it should wait.

Edit: I meant to << onto the array, not set it equal.

Comment: Yep, I agree - this looks relevant.

Comment: Oooops, but it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. Calling status on the threads reveals that one by one they disappear :(